# React Native using both Props and Navigation in Component

Tags: react-native

How can I use both Navigation and Props in a Component?

```
const Foobar = ({ navigation, props }) => (
  <Container>
    <TitleBar onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
      <Title>{props.title}</Title>
    </TitleBar>
  </Container>
);
export default Foobar;
```

But error I get is:
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.title')`

When I call this:

`import Foobar from "./components/Foobar";`

`<Foobar title="Hey" />`

When using it like this, the `props` work, but `navigation` doesn't:

```
const Foobar = (props) => (
```

Comment: I think you should unpack your props like ```const Foobar = ({ navigation, title })```

Comment: @sushrut619 also not working

Comment: print out the props before unpacking it and see if it has a title attribute. If it does not have a title attribute then probably you are not setting the prop correctly when you call the ```Foobar``` component.

something like this

```const Foobar = (props) => { print(props); }```

Comment: @sushrut619 props are working fine.. navigation part not

Comment: your original question mentions issue with ```props.title```. Seems like you managed to solve the issue with ```title``` ?
If you are facing trouble with navigation then you will have to update the question accordingly.
If Foobar is not a screen component in your navigator stack, then you need to pass navigation prop [explicitly](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop). If you simply need to navigate and do not need navigation prop for any other purpose, then you could also use [NavigationHelper](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use your component inside any screen pass that screen's navigation to the component as a prop. It should work I had same problems many times I used it like this

Example:

```js
    import React from "react"
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native"
    import Foobar from "./components/Foobar"
    
    export default function Demo({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Foobar title="Hey" navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
      )
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

To use both `navigation` and `props`, declare your component as below:

```js
const Foobar = ({ navigation, ...props }) => ( // add three dots before the props
  <Container>
    <TitleBar onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
      <Title>{props.title}</Title>
    </TitleBar>
  </Container>
);
export default Foobar;
```

Now, you can use both `navigation` and `props`.

This is called **Destructuring assignment**. You can read more about thar [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

**Note:** `Foobar` component should be in your Navigation Container.

Answer (score -2):

Get navigation directly from the react navigation hook in the functional component which you are using

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and change your function as

```
const Foobar = (props) => {
const navigation = useNavigation()
return(
<Container>
<TitleBar onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
  <Title>{props.title}</Title>
</TitleBar>
</Container>
)};
export default Foobar;
```

Comment: Then I get "Invalid hook call".

Comment: I have edited the answer.please have a look.

Comment: Not useful either